# VPN and IP on Windows

Tags: windows-10, vpn

If I use a VPN when windows starts, does windows know my IP address, when using my VPN I can see in windows network settings my real IP, does this means Microsoft knows and collects my real IP?

Comment: Your computer needs to know information about all these things to *actually work*, that doesn't correlate to it transmitting everything you do to "Microsoft". Your VPN provider knows more about what you are doing than Microsoft does, why should you trust them more?

Answer (score -2):

A VPN hides your IP from the sites you visit. It depends if Windows uses the VPN when sending requests to Microsoft. But in reality, they have a bunch of telemetry on Windows. So I would say yes, Microsoft probably knows and collects your real IP.

There is also Windows Updates too.

Comment: Microsoft has your IP due to your machine checking in for Windows Updates, that doesn't mean that they automatically collect "telemetry" on you to track everything you do.

Comment: tbh, this is a paranoid answer to an equally paranoid question. Honestly, 'Big Brother' doesn't really care that much about you. Your VPN provider would be more suspect than Microsoft in any transaction of this type. Who know who they're selling their customer lists to.